# Multiple attributes to be indexed for unstructured objects

Tags: mysql, indexing, entity-attribute-value, database, nosql

I asked similar question in context of a NOSQL DB on SO [Indexing on several fields in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510371/indexing-on-several-fields-in-mongodb), soon to realize its not to do with any DB, but a general design problem. I'll try to formulate the query again so it sounds generic:

I need to store information per object in some DB. Each object can have a variable number of attributes, each attribute name may also be different. We can put a cap on number of attributes to 10, if that makes our lives easier, may be in relational DB world.

Object 1:

```
name : "Cupboard Number 1"
type: "Cupboard"
material : "Wood"
dimensions : "12X15"
built on : "2nd oct 2014"
id : 12212
```

Object 2:

```
name : "Tommy"
type : "Pet"
owner : "Tom"
born : "1 June 2010"
id : 12321
```

So each object may have different attributes/fields. I'd like to have the flexibility to query on this database by filtering on any combination of attributes. Since the database can be enormous, I'd like data retrieval to be fast, for which I'd want some kind of indexing to be possible which expedites the query.

The example query may be:

- Search all records which have material = "Wood" and type = "Table"
- Search all records which have type = "Dog" and owner = "Harry"

I was thinking of using a table/collection where all the attributes can fit into one object, but cannot see how indexing would be possible. I can obviously break down the object into individual attribute objects and then store it which would mean having something like this:

Object 1 has multiple individual rows/objects:

```
{ "attr_name" : "name", "attr_value" : "Cupboard Number 1", "id" : 12212 }
{ "attr_name" : "type", "attr_value" : "Cupboard", "id" : 12212 }
{ "attr_name" : "material", "attr_value" : "Wood", "id" : 12212 }
{ "attr_name" : "dimensions", "attr_value" : "12X15", "id" : 12212 }
{ "attr_name" : "built on", "attr_value" : "2nd oct 2014", "id" : 12212 }
```

Now I can create index on attr_name and get 'id', which I can use to gather all the records for that object. However, this would not straightaway work beyond one attribute, while my requirement is to filter for several attributes in one query. If I had to make it work beyond one filter attribute, then I'll need to run multiple queries per filter attribute, and then join all of the results on "id". Not efficient the way I see it.

Lets simplify things to assume there would not be more than 10 attributes for any object. So we can potentially have a RDBMS table which has one column per attribute name, and one column for that attribute's value. So we can have a giant table schema like this:

```
attrName1 // attribute 1 Name
attrName2 // attribute 2 Name
...
attrVal1 // attribute 1 Value
attrVal2 // attribute 2 Value
..
id
```

So the Object 1 can potentially be inserted as follows:

```
('name', 'type', 'material', 'dimensions', 'built on', '','','','','','Cupboard Number 1','Cupboard','Wood','12X15','2ndOctober 2014',,,,,,12212)
```

Having individual indexes on all the columns 1-10 would speed up the query (although it would still perform joins, which is bad). That's one workaround for this problem, but then we need to be aware of the order in which the attributes appear in the row (material is in column 3, etc). I am looking for approach which can solve this problem in a more elegant fashion. Any DB is okay, and let me know if there are links to blogs which have attempted solving something like this.

Comment: Search for "EAV" or "key-value".  You will find a lot of people moaning about poor performance, plus a few suggestions.  It's a tough problem.  [My blog on EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)